# How to use boost::function_types::parameter_types with ClassTypeTransform

Tags: c++, boost

I have been toying with an example hpp provided in the boost library and I am trying to figure out how to use this parameter_types function correctly.

From the [boost doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/function_types/doc/html/boost_functiontypes/reference/decomposition.html#boost_functiontypes.reference.decomposition.parameter_types), parameter_types needs a ClassTypeTransform in order to parse class member function signatures.

I want to parse member function signatures, but I cannot find any doc on what this lamda expression is supposed to do.

> ClassTransform
>       MPL - Lambda Expression to transform the class type if F is a
>   member function pointer

Which is from the page itself, I cannot find any sample code actually using it and I was hoping someone know how to use it to parse member function signatures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ClassTransform` is simply used to modify the first argument type in case `parameter_types<>` is applied to a member function pointer type. The default is `add_reference<_>`, so for instance:

```
parameter_types<void(X::*)(int)>::type -> SomeSequence<void, X&, int>
parameter_types<void(X::*)(int), mpl::identity<_> >::type -> SomeSequence<void, X, int>
parameter_types<void(X::*)(int), add_pointer<_> >::type -> SomeSequence<void, X*, int>
```